# No space left on device - Android emulator

Tags: java, android

I've got an error and i don't know why, i googled it many time but nothing appeared.

com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device

I clean and build the project... Nothing. I don't know what to do next.
I'm talking about the emulator.

Comment: You can try by deleting the current avd and create a new one with greater sdcard

Comment: @BrockAdams no it's not, it's a different exception

Answer (score 1):

uninstall existing application and try.
or
delete your sd card and create new sd card with size 2047 mb.
or
during running the application scroll down the run window and write 
"-partition-size 2047"  below thw line  *additional emulator command Line option.*

Comment: You present a list of different choices.  It would be good to explain a little more about what each choice does, why you think this approach will help, and link to any documentation or blogs you think relevant.